# SEM: Replicating Proc CALIS (SAS) in Python

Tags: python, r, statistics, sas, structural-equation-model

I have been running SEM in SAS using PROC CALIS in the past. Now I need to transition to R or Python. (Initially transition started to R but due to some internal conflict, now everything needs to be transitioned to python). The problem is - output between SAS/R is not matching with Python.

For testing purpose in am using Iris dataset in SAS/R/Python.

```
SAS Process
==========

proc corr data = IRIS cov outp= covmat (type = cov)  noprint; 
run;

proc calis data = covmat cov outram = stats METHOD = ML PRINT RESIDUAL STDERR  MAXFUNC=10000 MAXITER=10000;

   lineqs
    SepalLength  = 1  fsingle + e1 ,
    SepalWidth   = l2 fsingle + e2 ,
    PetalLength  = l3 fsingle + e3 ;
    std
         e1 - e3 = u1 - u3,
         fSingle = x1;
   ods output AsymStdRes = AsymStdRes;
run;

R Process
==========

library (lavaan)

IRIS = as.data.frame(iris[,-5])
colnames(IRIS) <- c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth','PetalLength', 'PetalWidth')

covmat <- cov (IRIS, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")

model_structure <- 'fsingle =~ SepalLength + SepalWidth + PetalLength'
SEM_Fit <- sem(model_structure,sample.cov = covmat ,sample.nobs = 150) 
parameterEstimates(SEM_Fit)


Python Process
==========

import semopy as sp   
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

IRIS = pd.DataFrame(load_iris()['data'],columns= ['SepalLength', 'SepalWidth','PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'])

covmat = IRIS.cov()

model_structure = 'fsingle =~ SepalLength + SepalWidth + PetalLength'
model = sp.Model(model_structure)
fit = model.fit(data=None,obj='MLW',cov=covmat , n_samples=150)
model.inspect()
```

SAS and R outputs are similar, but python is different

```
SAS Output
==========
                 Effects in Linear Equations 
Variable     Predictor Parameter Estimate Standard Error t Value Pr > |t| 
SepalLength fsingle               1.00000       
SepalWidth  fsingle     l2       -0.25869    0.05249      -4.9285 <.0001 
PetalLength fsingle     l3        7.76868    4.18211       1.8576 0.0632 

                 Estimates for Variances of Exogenous Variables 
Variable Type Variable Parameter Estimate Standard Error t Value Pr > |t| 
Error
                e1        u1      0.52166    0.10299       5.0653 <.0001 
                e2        u2      0.17900    0.02148       8.3349 <.0001 
                e3        u3     -6.78348    5.09361      -1.3318 0.1829 
Latent         fsingle    x1      0.16403    0.09804       1.6731 0.0943 

R Output
==========
          lhs op         rhs    est    se      z pvalue ci.lower ci.upper
1     fsingle =~ SepalLength  1.000 0.000     NA     NA    1.000    1.000
2     fsingle =~  SepalWidth -0.259 0.052 -4.945  0.000   -0.361   -0.156
3     fsingle =~ PetalLength  7.769 4.168  1.864  0.062   -0.401   15.938
4 SepalLength ~~ SepalLength  0.518 0.102  5.082  0.000    0.318    0.718
5  SepalWidth ~~  SepalWidth  0.178 0.021  8.363  0.000    0.136    0.219
6 PetalLength ~~ PetalLength -6.738 5.043 -1.336  0.181  -16.622    3.145
7     fsingle ~~     fsingle  0.163 0.097  1.679  0.093   -0.027    0.353

Python Output
==========
          lval  op         rval      Estimate  Std. Err   z-value   p-value
0  SepalLength   ~      fsingle  1.000000e+00         -         -         -
1   SepalWidth   ~      fsingle -2.586642e-01  0.046093 -5.611781       0.0
2  PetalLength   ~      fsingle  2.445366e+00  0.261872  9.338026       0.0
3      fsingle  ~~      fsingle  5.211881e-01  0.091938  5.668913       0.0
4  SepalLength  ~~  SepalLength  1.645862e-01  0.053893   3.05394  0.002259
5  PetalLength  ~~  PetalLength  5.687993e-16  0.301568       0.0       1.0
6   SepalWidth  ~~   SepalWidth  1.550831e-01  0.018223  8.510495       0.0
```

**I have 3 questions -**

1. Why am I not able to match Python output with SAS/R. What am I missing here?
2. I will be using multiple outputs but parameter estimates and residual matrix are most important for my analysis. How do I get residual matrix in python?
3. Below mentioned model structures are what I need usually run with in SAS. How to replicate them in Python?

```
Model Structure 2 
==========

proc calis data = covmat cov outram = stats METHOD = ML PRINT RESIDUAL STDERR  MAXFUNC=10000 MAXITER=10000;

   lineqs
    SepalLength  = 1  fSepal + e1 ,
    SepalWidth   = L1 fSepal + e2 ,
    PetalLength  = L2 fPetal + e3 ;
    
    Cov
    fSepal
    fPetal
    = cov1;
    
    Std
    fSepal
    fPetal
    = phi1 phi2

    e1 - e3 = u1 - u3;
  
run;

Model Structure 2
==========

proc calis data = covmat cov outram = stats METHOD = ML PRINT RESIDUAL STDERR  MAXFUNC=10000 MAXITER=10000;

   lineqs
    SepalLength  = 1  fSepal + e1 ,
    SepalWidth   = L1 fSepal + e2 ,
    PetalLength  = L2 fPetal + e3 ,

    fSepal = lam1 fsecond + es1,
    fPetal = lam2 fsecond + es2,

    PetalWidth = fSepal + fPetal + d1;
        
    Std
    fsecond  = 1,
    e1 - e3  = u1 - u3,
    es1- es2 = us1- us2,
          d1 = v1;
run;
```

Comment: Your question includes multiple questions at once.  Please focus your posts on one problem at a time.  Also, your current Python code is not valid Python code and we are unable to reproduce your problem as we don't know how you created your data. What is the `fsingle` column for example?  Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @AlexK `fSingle` is a latent variable in SEM construct. You don't need that in the data. I spotted a small issue in the above code, I had used `<-` instead of `=` for python, which doesn't work. I have also included a small script on how you can get the IRIS data so that you can replicate the above code. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can't provide answers myself, but three things to suggest: (1) available `mimic_lavaan=` parameter when initializing the model: `model = sp.Model(model_structure, mimic_lavaan=True)` (source code [here](https://gitlab.com/georgy.m/semopy/-/blob/master/semopy/model.py#L56)), (2) ability to open issues with the `semopy` maintainers (https://semopy.com/support.html), (3) a recent [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/360439072_CB-SEM_IMPLEMENTATION_IN_R_AND_PYTHON_A_REVIEW_AND_COMPARATIVE_STUDY) compares `lavaan` and `semopy`.

Comment: I just tried option 1). - Did not help. Outputs are still different. Will try option 2) and 3). Thanks for providing these.